# Porting shader to Godot 4.0

Tags: shader, godot

I found this shader in a comment on Shadertoy, produces a rectangle with round corners:

```
float udRoundBox( vec2 p, vec2 b, float r )
{
  return length(max(abs(p)-b+r,0.0))-r;
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    float f = udRoundBox( fragCoord-iResolution.xy/2.0, iResolution.xy/2.0, 64.0);
    f = (f>0.0) ? 1.0 : 0.0;
    fragColor = vec4(f,1.0,f,1.0);
}
```

I attempted to transcribe it to Godot 4.0 shading language:

```
shader_type canvas_item;

float udRoundBox( vec2 p, vec2 b, float r )
{
    return length(max(abs(p)-b+r,0.0))-r;
}

void fragment()
{
    // Vague idea of how to translate these:
    vec2  iResolution = SCREEN_PIXEL_SIZE;
    vec2  fragCoord = FRAGCOORD.xy;
    vec4  fragColor = COLOR;
    
    vec2  p = fragCoord-iResolution.xy/2.0;
    vec2  b = iResolution.xy/2.0;
    float r = 64.0;
    
    float f = udRoundBox(p, b, r);
    f = (f>0.0) ? 1.0 : 0.0;
    fragColor = vec4(f,1.0,f,1.0);
}
```

But when added as a new shader material to a TextureRect with GradientTexture1D, it does not change the look of the texture in any way. I tried tweaking `r` but again, no difference. What is the problem?

Comment: You are not setting COLOR = fragColor at the end, so your shader currently does nothing except some calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not setting COLOR at the end of your shader, it outputs nothing. Also I would not bother with screen coordinates if you want shader to work locally on the attached object.

```
shader_type canvas_item;

float udRoundBox( vec2 p, vec2 b, float r )
{
    return length(max(abs(p)-b+r,0.0))-r;
}

void fragment()
{
    vec4  fragColor = COLOR;
    
    //  translate UV range from [0, 1] to [-1, 1]
    vec2  p = UV*2.0 - 1.0;
    vec2  b = vec2(1.0);
    float r = 0.25;
    
    float f = udRoundBox(p, b, r);
    f = (f>0.0) ? 1.0 : 0.0;
    fragColor = vec4(f,1.0,f,1.0);
    COLOR = fragColor;
}
```